# Categorical general topology -- reference request

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, category-theory

I am looking for literature describing general topology in terms of category theory. I would prefer literature which does not assume too much familiarity with category theory, but would appreciate any coherent refrences.

Comment: There are books by Preuss and Herrlich IIRC.

Comment: Is there a chance that you happen to know their names? I've found one book by Preuss called foundations of topology, is this the one you had in mind?

Comment: That book is more of a general topology text book with more focus on category theory ideas. So it might interest you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recall G. Preuß' book *Theory of Topological Structures: An Approach to Categorical Topology* and some works by [Horst Herrlich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horst_Herrlich) (references at that page) as well.

There have been some conferences on "categorical topology" of which there are proceedings (e.g. [this one](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540078593) or [this one](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540095033) etc.; this is all pretty old and in vogue in the 70's). [This survey](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265844500_Categorical_Topology) might interest you as well, being more recent.

Also, "pointless topology" and frames/locales might interest you as well. This has connections to logic and geometry.

Comment: Also, "Foundations of Topology" from G. Preuss is an excellent reference